How I decrease the gas fee when I call the contract method?
Deploying my contract on rinkeby cost ~12 USD in gas fees (using truffle cli). Is it possible for me to specify gas fees/set a limit in the smart contract so it costs me 0.5 USD, but takes longer to deploy ?

As mentioned in the Truffle docs:

gasPrice: Gas price used for deploys. Default is 20000000000
(20 Gwei).

So, you can override that value with your desired amount (in wei) by setting the same in the networks object of your truffle-config.js file, like:
networks: {
    rinkeby: {
        ... // Other configurations
        gasPrice: 5000000000 // 5 Gwei (in wei)
    }
}

